# how to append an existing form on button click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given some html, a form named `InterfacesIx` and a button named `addInterfacesIx`

```
                <div class="step-new-content white-text">
                    <p class="text-monospace"><small>helps you rollout a configlet about blahblah</small></p>
                    <form name="InterfacesIx">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="md-form col-12">
                            <input type="text" name="xxx" class="form-control white-text" placeholder="123"><label for="xxx">asn</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="md-form col-12">
                            <textarea name="yyy" class="md-textarea form-control white-text" rows="3"></textarea><label for="yyy">notes</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br><br>
                    </form>
                    <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <button type="button" name="addInterfacesIx" class="btn btn-block btn-flat"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I would like to clone/duplicate the form when the user clicks on the `addInterfacesIx` button using jQuery I guess.

The jQuery that I am trying looks like this:

```
        <script>
         $(document).ready(() => {

             $('addInterfacesIx').click(function(){
                 $('InterfacesIx').clone().insertBefore('addInterfacesIx');
             });
         });
        </script>
```

When I do `console.log($('InterfacesIx'));` nothing gets printed out. Is the selector wrong ?
When inspecting the form element on the browser I get:

- copy attribute shows `name="InterfacesIx"`
- copy selector path shows `#stepper-navigation > li > div.step-new-content.white-text > form`
- copy xml shows `//*[@id="stepper-navigation"]/li/div[2]/form`

Would you be so kind to advise what I am doing wrong and how to achieve the desired result ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you, can you provide an example please with the provided jQuery in mind ?

Comment: I added an answer for you below

Comment: awesome! works!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would appreciate your expert help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60280242/how-to-append-an-existing-form-that-gets-rendered-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('addInterfacesIx')` and `$('InterfacesIx')` aren't valid selectors. I'd suggest putting id/class attributes on the relevant elements and then selecting them by that.

I also assume that the `form` elements should be siblings, as such try using `insertAfter()` and placing the new form after the last one currently in the DOM. Your current logic would place the new form inside the button container. Try this:

```js
jQuery(($) => {
  $('#addInterfacesIx').click(function() {
    $('.interfacesIx:first').clone().insertAfter('.interfacesIx:last');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step-new-content white-text">
  <p class="text-monospace"><small>helps you rollout a configlet about blahblah</small></p>
  <form name="InterfacesIx" class="interfacesIx">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="md-form col-12">
        <input type="text" name="xxx" class="form-control white-text" placeholder="123"><label for="xxx">asn</label>
      </div>
      <div class="md-form col-12">
        <textarea name="yyy" class="md-textarea form-control white-text" rows="3"></textarea><label for="yyy">notes</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
  </form>
  <div class="col-12 text-center">
    <button type="button" name="addInterfacesIx" id="addInterfacesIx" class="btn btn-block btn-flat"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector `$('addInterfacesIx')` is not valid. If you want to grab an element by name you should use attribute selector, something like this: `$( "form[name='addInterfacesIx']")`. However, as mentioned before, grabbing element by class or ID is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the fact that a `name` attribute is not normally used as a jQuery selector - the `name` attribute is normally used for keys to form values when they are submitted to the server. You can select elements using the name attribute, as indicated by the code below, but using `id` and `class` attributes is preferred.

```
 <form id="InterfacesIx" name="InterfacesIx">
 ...
 </form>
 <div class="col-12 text-center">
   <button type="button" id="addInterfacesIx" class="btn btn-block btn-flat"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
 </div>

 <script>
     $(document).ready(() => {

         $('#addInterfacesIx').click(function(){
             // $('#InterfacesIx') is better
             $('[name=InterfacesIx]').clone().insertBefore('addInterfacesIx');
         });
     });
    </script>
```