# how to append an existing form with select form fields using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given some html, a form named `inputPrefixListIx` and a button named `addPrefixListIx`

```
<div id="divinputPrefixListIx" name="divinputPrefixListIx">
    <form name="inputPrefixListIx" class="inputPrefixListIx">
        <div class="row">

                <div class="col-12">
                    <select name="spec" class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select dropdown-primary">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>spec</option>
                        <option value="replace" data-secondary-text="">replace</option>
                        <option value="delete" data-secondary-text="">delete</option>
                    </select>
                    <label class="mdb-main-label">spec</label>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <br><br><br>
    </form>

    <div class="col-12">
        <button type="button" name="addPrefixListIx" id="addPrefixListIx" class="btn btn-block btn-flat"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>

</div>
```

I would like to clone/duplicate the form when the user clicks on the `addPrefixListIx` button using jQuery I guess.

The jQuery used (and works partially) looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/blueprints.js"></script>

jQuery(($) => {

    // PrefixListIx
    $('#addPrefixListIx').click(function() {
        $('.inputPrefixListIx:first').clone().insertAfter('.inputPrefixListIx:last');
    });
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('PrefixListIx') !== null) {
        $('#divinputPrefixListIx').addClass('d-none');
    }
    else {
        $('#divmanifestPrefixListIx').addClass('d-none');
    }
    $('#delPrefixListIx').click(function() {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('PrefixListIx');
        $('#divinputPrefixListIx').toggleClass('d-none');
        $('#divmanifestPrefixListIx').toggleClass('d-none');
    });

});
```

What doesn't work is that the options of the select form fields do not appear.

Would you be so kind to advise what I am doing wrong and how to fix this ?

**EDIT:** I encountered this [Clone isn't cloning select values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742810/clone-isnt-cloning-select-values) which suggests a fix available here https://github.com/spencertipping/jquery.fix.clone but I don't know how to use it given the provided example, can somebody please advise ?

Comment: using `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` seems not to solve the issue

Comment: I remember it happened to me once can you check with this $("#addPrefixListIx").on("click", function(){ ...} and let me know if that works.

Comment: @Manjuboyz unfortunately, no luck. But, please do see the new 'edit'...